# Doxygen raw markdown (no comment blocks)

Tags: c++, markdown, doxygen

At the moment I am doing something like this:

https://bitbucket.org/chancey/eagle/src/ae5572b842f8122afc52678b0f02507b4eedd490/manual/manual/internals/sorting.h

But it would be much easier to use Markdown. Can I use Markdown without encapsulating the whole page in the `/** */` fence which causes my IDE to mess with the indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (using Doxygen 1.8+)

1. Change the file extension to `.md` (or `.markdown`)
2. You also need to add `*.md` / `*.markdown` to `FILE_PATTERNS` in the Doxyfile.